# How to get both exceptions if a child object and a parent object have an exception thrown

Tags: c#, exception

In C#, if a child object has try catch block of code, and a parent object also has a try catch block of code, if the child object throws an exception, how can I get the details for both of the exceptions?

Here is the exception class:

```
public class CompileObjectException : InvalidOperationException
{
    private ICustomObject _ownerCustomObject { get; set; }
    public ICustomObject OwnerCustomObject
    {
        get
        {
            return _ownerCustomObject;
        }
        set
        {
            _ownerCustomObject = value;
        }
    }
    public CompileObjectException()
    {

    }
    public CompileObjectException(ICustomObject ownerCustomObject, string message)
        : base(message)
    {
        _ownerCustomObject = ownerCustomObject;
    }
}
```

When the `CompileObjectException` is thrown in both of the objects, the `OwnerCustomObject` is set to the object that the exception is thrown in.

In the above code, I am wanting to get the `OwnerCustomObject` for both the parent and child objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, the parent object will throw the exception with the child exception in the InnerException. InnerExceptions can have InnerExceptions, so you can go all the way down to the root cause.

EDIT:

The pattern looks like:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
   try
   {
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      throw new MyException(message, e);
   }
}

class MyException : Exception
{
   public MyException(string message, Exception inner)
   : base(message, inner)
   {
   }
}
```

Obviously there are other details, but that's how you would return both.

Comment: When looking at the InnerException, the value is null. Do I have to code this into my CompileObjectException class?

Comment: Note that there are cases when caller will explicitly not propagate exception information and you get `null` for inner exception - i.e. server side code usually have top level exception handlers that will mask all errors that may leak configuration info like `SqlException`.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of argument, I'll assume your `ICustomObject` has a single property on it, and a concrete class that implements it, like this:

```
public class CustomObject : ICustomObject
{
    public string Scope { get; set; }
}

public interface ICustomObject
{
    string Scope { get; set; }
}
```

By default, the `ToString()` method on the `Exception` class recursively loops through all `InnerException`'s  so that it displays everything available to the user.

You'll have to do things slightly differently, if you want to get the value of that custom object.

First, modify your custom exception class to accept an `InnerException` and pass it to the `base`.

```
public CompileObjectException(ICustomObject ownerCustomObject, string message, Exception innerException = null)
    : base(message, innerException)
{
    _ownerCustomObject = ownerCustomObject;
}
```

Then override the `ToString()` method to loop through each `InnerException`, and create a custom message that includes the value of your `CustomObject` class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return GetInnerException(this);
}

private string GetInnerException(CompileObjectException e)
{
    if (e == null)
        return "";

    return string.Format("{0} ({1}) \n{2}", e.Message, e.OwnerCustomObject.Scope, GetInnerException((CompileObjectException)e.InnerException));
}
```

Now when you call several nested methods, and they each throw an exception, you can save all those exceptions and display them to the user.

```
public static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        ParentMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);  // implicitly calls e.ToString()
    }

}

public static void ParentMethod()
{
    try
    {
        ChildMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new CompileObjectException(new CustomObject {Scope = "P"}, "Parent Message", e);
    }
}

public static void ChildMethod()
{
    try
    {
        YetAnotherChild();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new CompileObjectException(new CustomObject {Scope = "C"}, "Child Message", e);
    }
}

public static void YetAnotherChild()
{
    throw new CompileObjectException(new CustomObject {Scope = "C2"}, "Another Child Message");
}
```

You'll probably want to customize this for your particular case, but the above will display a chain similar to this...

```
Parent Message (P) 
Child Message (C) 
Another Child Message (C2)
```